# catch2: how to execute another process as part of test case?

Tags: catch2, catch-unit-test

i'm trying to implement a test case in catch2 that tests usage of fifo between processes.
For testing it, i want to run another process that creates and writes to fifo, while my test (using catch2) will read from this fifo.
Is there a way to run a process using catch2 or i just use regular system APIs for execution another exe file (process) as part of the test?

Thanks